# React State value not updaing on click for first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am having input tag with `id="Table"` with state dynamictable.

```
 this.state = {
      dynamictable: ""
   }
 <input type="text" className="form-control box_ip" placeholder="Table" 
  id="Table"   value={this.state.dynamictable}/>
```

And I have a button `next` and on click on button i am calling a function `updateEditorData()`

```
updateEditorData() {

  this.setState({
        dynamictable: "Hello"
    });

this.table.forEach((id) => {
       let element = document.getElementById(id);
        if (element != undefined) {
            if (element.value != undefined && element.value != '') {
            this.replaceText(id, element.value);



            }
        }
    })

}
```

On click on `next` for the first time `this.replaceText()` is not getting called, because as element.value is `""` but for the second type element.value is coming `"hello"` But why for the first time it is not calling that function and as the initial state of dynamictable is `""`?

I need to call `this.replaceText()` for the first time only, It means on click on `next button`  for the first time i need to update the state with empty string to "hello"

Thanks in Advance. Please guide me.

Comment: [`this.setState()` doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) quote: "setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later." The doc also contains the solution to your problem.

Comment: is there a reason, you don't use the render method to render your table with the correct updated data?

Answer (score 1):

[`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) works async, so immediately after invoking it, `this.state` may be unchanged. However, there is an optional second parameter to `setState` called `callback` in the docs, which gets invoked, as soon as the state has been updated:

```
this.setState({dynamictable: "Hello"}, () => {
  this.table.forEach(...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.setState()` is asynchronous in react. What means when you are calling
`this.setState({dynamictable: "Hello"});` its not inmediate.
So, if you are using that state just after doing setState it probably wont be updated yet.